# Bug using geometryfunction in OpenLayers 3 clustering

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to exclude certain features from being clustered, by using the geometryfunction as described in the API here:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html

It is recommended to return null, when the feature should not be considered for clustering. I would expect that to mean, that the feature would still be shown, but not included in clusters. What i see is, that the feature is not shown at all. Is this to be expected?

```
IconLayer.clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    geometryFunction: this.clusterFunction,
    source: mySource,            
});

private clusterFunction(icon: Icon) {
    return icon.geo.isMoving ? null : icon.getGeometry();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it cant be done that way. See this answer on github:

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4917#issuecomment-224875452

As describe in the above link, a possible solution is to create a 2nd vector layer and show the non clustered features there.

EDIT: For the record i ended up creating two vector layers. But instead of using geometryFunction to disable rendering on the first layer, i simply removed the feature in question from the source of the first layer and added it to the second.